# How do I apply a hover overlay to a 2 x 2 grid of 4 seperate image maps?

Tags: html, css

I would like to add this type of hover text overlay:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_image_overlay_fade

to an image grid that looks something like this:
https://dab1nmslvvntp.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/1456867697gridlayout05.jpg

What would the HTML & CSS look like for this? When I tried adding one hover overlay, my image grid ended up breaking and the images began stacking on top of each other.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and modify your question

Answer (score 0):

To do this you can easily do it using CSS2 Float concept. Just take the Tweets and Replies part in row-1 div and add float left with clearfix to Tweets and to Replies with float Right. And then coming to the next row i.e. row-2 similarly add float left with clearfix to Search and to Messages with float Right. And this would do the work using CSS2. There other ways as well using CSS3 but I find this one here easy to use.